# grails plugins maven repo

Tags: svn, grails, maven, grails-plugin

Is there any maven open repository that contains grails plugins.
Or some workaround that allow connect my maven repository and svn repository with grails plugins?

Thanks, Pavel.

Comment: There is no Maven repository for grails plugins, which I'm aware of. Incredibly annoying "feature" of Grails when deployed into an Enterprise environment :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that grails maven central http://repo.grails.org/grails now contains grails-plugins.